# bad formating of ff in math mode

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I'm trying to write something like: `$affinity(x)$`, but in the PDF I see some small spacing between the two f's.

[image: example image]

I tried `$af{}firm(x)$` or `$aff{}irm(x)$`, but nothing works.

Comment: In general math words should not be entered "undecorated" in TeX as they are typeset as separate letters, not as a word....which is why we use \mathit and the like.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`$\mathit{affinity}(x)$`

Answer (score 15):

How do you usually write maps, functions and operators in your math text? Italic as well?

Math operators are commonly written in upright letters, in contrary to variables which have italic shape. I would use `\mathrm` instead of `\mathit` or better

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\affinity}{affinity}
```

of amsmath, and write `\affinity` in the formulas. Here's a complete example, just compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\affinity}{affinity}
\begin{document}
\[
  \affinity(x) \neq \mathit{affinity}(x) \neq y(x),
\]
\[
  \max_f \lim_a af = a\cdot f
\]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

`$affinity$` stands for the product of the variables *a*, *f*, *f*, *i*, …. Wordlike functions are usually written in an upright font, usually with `\DeclareMathOperator`:

```
\usepackage{amsopn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\affinity}{affinity}
```

Comment: I agree, just wrote it at the same time :) just with an example.